# wordcloud package: get "Error in strwidth(...) : invalid 'cex' value"

Tags: tm

I am using the tm and wordcloud packages in R 2.15.1.
I am trying to make a word cloud from a DTM. Here is the code:

```
library(wordcloud)
thedtmsparse = inspect(sparse)
trymatrix = t(thedtmsparse)
colnames(trymatrix) = c()
comparison.cloud(trymatrix, max.words=15, random.order=FALSE)
```

I get the following error from the last command:

```
Error in strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ...) : invalid 'cex' value
```

I have used the same code on another DTM where it worked fine and I got the word cloud.
Can somebody tell me a fix for the error?

Ravi

Answer (score 5):

You haven't provided reproducible code (probably a big reason no one answered your question), so I can only venture to guess what the problem might be.

I faced this same error, so I'll share my experience.  The problem was I had `NA`'s instead of `0`'s in my term document matrix.  Simply fixing that fixed that problem.

Comment: DF <- DF[!DF$text == '',] fixed my problem.